# Adding external Dom elements (onkeyup and onchange) function into input text, select) with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to add the `onkeyup='previewText()` function here from the `previewText()` function

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" **onkeyup="previewText()"** placeholder="Enter text here">
```

I want to add the `onchange="changeFont()` function here from the `changeFont()` function

```
<select id="fontSelector" **onchange="changeFont()"**>
```

---

My Codes

```js
function previewText() {
  var text = document.getElementById("703564").value;
  document.getElementById("preview").innerText = text;
}

function changeFont() {
  var font = document.getElementById("815439").value;
  document.getElementById("preview").style.fontFamily = font;
}
```

```css
#preview {
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="703564" onkeyup="previewText()" placeholder="Enter text here" />

<select id="815439" onchange="changeFont()">
  <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
  <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>

<div id="preview">Preview Text</div>
```

I tried javascript dom element manipulation but couldn't get it to work

Comment: I added your event handlers to your snippet as you explained and it's working fine. That being said it is better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to control handlers, and the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event is more appropriate for realtime input tracking.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. An example using the above suggestions here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuvw16hm/1/)